# What did I do wrong with my html/css website?

Tags: html, css, debugging

I am busy making a website and have trouble with a vertical navigation menu. My first approach was to try to delete some lines of code to see if something blocks what I want it to do but I just cant seem to find it.
The second thing I tried to do was search for a vertical navigation menu similiar to mine but I couldnt find one exactly similiar.
So my question is how can I fix this?
This is how it is acting now: [Image now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZc5M.png)
This is how I want it to act: [How I want it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1JkQ.png)

My code is here:

```css
body{
 background-color:purple;
 height:100%;
}
.list{
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color:black;
 origin: top left;
 margin:8px 0 -50px -40px;
 width:210px;
 height:100%;
 
}
.button{
 background:grey;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
 padding:20px 25px 16px 25px;
 width:100px;
 border-radius:0 0 0 0;
 
 
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:17px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:Baskerville;
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none;
 transition-duration:0.4s;
}
.buttonA{
 background:#675bcc;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
 padding:20px 25px 16px 25px;
 width:100px;
 border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
 
 
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:17px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:Baskerville;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 transition-duration:0.4s;
}
.buttonB{
 background:grey;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
 padding:20px 25px 16px 25px;
 width:100px;
 border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
 
 
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:17px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:Baskerville;
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none;
 transition-duration:0.4s;
}
.button:hover, .buttonB:hover{
 background-color:purple;
 color:white;
 opacity:0.8;
}
.active-has-sub{
 
}
.has-sub{
 list-style-type: none;
 float:left;
 z-index:1;
 display:inline; 
 position:relative;
 top: -35px;
 left:140px;
}
.has-sub> a{
 text-decoration:none;
 text-align:left;
 
 background:grey;
 padding:20px 25px 16px 25px;
 font-size:15px;
}

.nav{
 background-color:black;
 origin: top left;
 margin:-8px 0 -50px -8px;
 width:210px;
 height:100%;
 z-index:1;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
<img src="" alt="logo.png" width=200px height=100px>
<ul class="list">

<li>
<a class="buttonA" href="#">Home</a>
</li>

<li class="active-has-sub" ><a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)">Herplaatsen</a> 
      <ul>
         <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Ik wil herplaatsen</a></li>
         <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Sub Product</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>

<li><a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)">Rescue's</a>

</li>
<li>
<a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)">Wil</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)">Handig</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)">Vakantie</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)">Opendag</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)">Doneren</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)">Sponser</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="buttonB" href="javascript:void(0)">Vakantieadres</a>
</li>
<br> 
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If someone could tell me what I did wrong and how I can fix this. 
That would be extremely helpfull and great :)

Answer (score 0):

The `<ul>` HTML tag just creates an unordered list, which would just create a plain vertical list, and by looking at the examples you have shared, it looks like a horizontal list is what you want. One way you could do this is by using the `<form>` HTML tag, which creates a form with all of the contents on the same line.

Here is an example of this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <a href="<link1>">Menu option 1</a>
        <a href="<link2>">Menu option 2</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This does something like this:
[Click here for image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E0RE.png)

This is not the best way of doing it, but it is one of the easiest.

Best of luck!